# What maven dependency need to have Class LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my project class LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean not found. I don't understand why? In other simple project with this class all works fine.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="simpleTest" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
    </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 10):

I use http://www.jarvana.com to look up maven dependencies.

I guess that you need spring-orm:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: **UPFDATE** [Jarvana is no more available](http://jarvana.blogspot.com/2013/08/goodbye-jarvana.html). One can use the official search engine for ["The Central Repository"](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|) or, as an alternative, [MVNrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/), or some other repo.